# Apple's website parallax effect

Tags: iphone, scroll, web, parallax, smoothing

I recently saw the "Design" page of Apple's presention of the iPhone 6S. They used a "parallax effect" for each of the iPhones. I know there are already existing parallax plugins available but Apple has that smooth effect that even works with "jerky" mouse knob. I really want to imitate that effect.

Here's the link [Apple iPhone 6S / Design](https://www.apple.com/fr/iphone-6s/design/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so I just found this perfect parallax scrolling plugin [Skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) and it's perfect.

Comment: Do you know of anything more recent and still under development?

Comment: skrollr hasn't been under active development since about September 2014 :(